# How to import the excel file to mySQL database using php

Tags: excel, import

I want to import the data in the excel to mySQL DB using php. I have tried using the way explained in other questions but nothing worked out for me. Kindly let me know how to import the data in to DB using php.

Also, do let me know where to place the excel file to be uploaded,I mean the location in the system.

Comment: This is not so hard... You can write your own implemenation. Try not using some 3rd pard software

Comment: I am new to php. Can you please help me in writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

method 1.you can use load data command

```
http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html
```

method 2. Excel reader

https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

method 3. parseCSV

```
https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php
```

method4. (PHP 4, PHP 5) fgetcsv

```
 http://in1.php.net/fgetcsv
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer this PHP code

```
<?php

 //table Name
$tableName = "MyTable";
//database name
$dbName = "MyDatabase";


 $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error());

//get the first row fields
$fields = "";
$fieldsInsert = "";
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    if(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $fieldsInsert .= '(';
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $fieldsInsert .=($c==0) ? '' : ', ';
            $fieldsInsert .="`".$data[$c]."`";
            $fields .="`".$data[$c]."` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,";
        }

        $fieldsInsert .= ')';
    }


    //drop table if exist
    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$tableName."'"))>=1) {
      mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `'.$tableName.'`') or die(mysql_error());
    }

    //create table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE `".$tableName."` (
              `".$tableName."Id` int(100) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              ".$fields."
              PRIMARY KEY (`".$tableName."Id`)
            ) ";

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                $num = count($data);
                $fieldsInsertvalues="";
                //get field values of each row
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    $fieldsInsertvalues .=($c==0) ? '(' : ', ';
                    $fieldsInsertvalues .="'".$data[$c]."'";
                }
                $fieldsInsertvalues .= ')';
                //insert the values to table
                $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tableName." ".$fieldsInsert."  VALUES  ".$fieldsInsertvalues;
                mysql_query($sql,$conn);   
        }
        echo 'Table Created';   
    }

    fclose($handle);

}

?>
```

Comment: I am getting the error as below fopen(protected/extensions/phpexcel/test1.xls): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: update the directory of file to just a file name and make sure that you have the privilege for access the file

Comment: I have tried giving only the file name. Kindly let me know where I have to place the file. Now I have placed it in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\ClaimSystem\claimNew\protected\extensions\phpexcel

Comment: you can keep it anywhere for eg:fopen("/home/mubeen/file.txt", "r");

Comment: if you don’t have privileges for access the particular folder then use chmod 777 <filenamehere> to give that

Comment: I have tried with the commands you have given still getting the same error.fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/www/ClaimSystem/claimNew/protected/extensions/phpexcel/test1.csv", "r") please confirm this is the correct command because I have placed the file in the below path C:\xampp\htdocs\www\ClaimSystem\claimNew\protected\extensions\phpexcel

Comment: command is correct only.did you try by adding the 777 permission

Comment: I tried but I am getting the error as below chmod(): No such file or directory

Comment: Hi Please let me know the way to sort out this issue. Thanks

Comment: @Burhan Khalid Please help me in the above issue. Thanks